# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I installed CKEditor by pip this command:

> pip install django_ckeditor==6.0.0

and installed correctly because there is files in virtenv.(image added at the end)
in my modules I have a class that use RichTextField:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
import datetime    
class Post(models.Model):
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        Text = RichTextField()
        Date = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
        Category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        Tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
        Banner_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
        Short_Story = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

but in the admin page when I go to the 'add post' link accord this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:40:29.936278 [UID:1812][18068] Child process with pid: 18089 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:40:31.015356 [UID:1812][18068] Child process with pid: 18136 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:41:26.705918 [UID:1812][18068] Child process with pid: 21740 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:41:27.803811 [UID:1812][18068] Child process with pid: 21783 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
2021-03-05 11:53:18.393443 [UID:1812][12783] Child process with pid: 12840 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
2021-03-05 11:53:19.516615 [UID:1812][12783] Child process with pid: 12958 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
2021-03-05 11:54:09.192662 [UID:1812][12783] Child process with pid: 22141 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:54:14.849770 [UID:1812][22487] Child process with pid: 22523 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:54:18.828664 [UID:1812][22487] Child process with pid: 22680 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
2021-03-05 11:54:21.817529 [UID:1812][22487] Child process with pid: 22887 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.wsgi import application
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home2/intellig/virtualenv/blog/3.6/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home2/intellig/blog/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
```

and here is my virtenv directory: [image: here]

how can I resolve it?

Comment: is your virtualenv activated?

Comment: I think yes, because the Django module works

Comment: you might have django installed globally though

Comment: @TenaciousB so how can i check that?

Comment: `source <venv>/bin/activate` where `<venv>` is your venv directory